# Early papers using statistical models for word completion?

Tags: natural-language, history

I am trying to find references about (early, as in pre-2000, but i would really love something pre-1990) statistical language models in word completion (like T-9, or Google's search autocomplete), but find it hard to find such papers. The best match i found was using statistical models to support semi-automated translations, but are there also works that went into that area "just to make (word processing) life a little easier"?

Comment: Have you tried tracing the bibliography sections of the paper backward? After a few generation backward you should be able to see something older. The terms might have changed along time so directly nailing down a pre-1990 paper maybe a bit challenging.